# php mysql inner join - get a particular row

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is my query to get model information from one table and a single picture from another table. What changes do I have to make to this query in order for it to get the picture where ORDER BY sort DESC? In the table of the pictures, there is a field by the name "sort". The default value for the field for each row is 0. But one random row has the value of 1. I want to get that particular row. I don't, however, want to use WHERE sort=1 because then even in the case where no row has the sort value 1, one row should still get fetched.

```
    $sql="SELECT tc.id,tc.alias,tc.firstname,tci.imagename 
          FROM ".$pre."models tc
          INNER JOIN ".$pre."model_images tci ON tc.id=tci.userid 
          WHERE activated=1 AND sex=$sex AND city=$city AND published=1
          GROUP BY tc.id ORDER BY firstname ASC";
```

Thank you in advance!

---

Solved using:

```
    SELECT tc.id,tc.alias,tc.firstname, 
    (SELECT imagename FROM  ".$pre."model_images WHERE userid= tc.id 
    ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 1) AS imagename
    FROM ".$pre."models tc
    WHERE tc.activated=1 AND tc.sex=1 AND tc.city=2 AND tc.published=1
    ORDER BY tc.firstname ASC
```

Comment: Question updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `ORDER BY sort DESC, firstname ASC` ?

Comment: Tried the above. Does't wor. Still returns sort=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place that in your WHERE clause aswell. One t hing to note though is to be carefull with the way you're using the column names. It's better to tell to which table they belong.

So this:

```
WHERE activated=1 AND sex=$sex AND city=$city AND published=1
```

Should be:

```
WHERE tc.activated=1 AND tc.sex=$sex AND tc.city=$city AND tc.published=1
```

And then simply add the 'sort' column to it:

```
WHERE tc.activated=1 AND tc.sex=$sex AND tc.city=$city AND tc.published=1 AND tci.sort=1
```

If no results are returned, then make sure that there are records that meet the required conditions. Because there's nothing wrong with the query. Try to print your query to the screen etc. to see if every variables has a value.

edit:

You should lose the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT tc.id,tc.alias,tc.firstname,tci.imagename 
FROM ".$pre."models tc
INNER JOIN ".$pre."model_images tci ON tc.id=tci.userid 
WHERE tc.activated=1 AND tc.sex=$sex AND tc.city=$city AND tc.published=1 AND tci.sort=1
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you please edit accordingly? Thank you!

Comment: Then I will have multiple order by's: GROUP BY tc.id ORDER BY firstname ASC. How do I go about that?

Comment: @salmanhijazi Not sure what you're really trying to do. Your GROUP BY is wrong. MySQL by default allows wrong queries like your GROUP BY. You're grouping by tc.id. I assume that's you're primary key? You can't group by something that is always unique. --- But if it's not unique, then you can still only show the column that you specify in your GROUP BY and some additional information with SUM(), AVG() etc. You can't just put any column in your SELECT when using a GROUP BY. It's hard to help you out without knowing exactly what you'r edoing and why you're trying to GROUP your results.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. What I'm trying to achieve is to fetch ALL models from the models table, and one picture for each from the images table. but each has 5-20 pictures, and I only want to fetch the one that has the sort value of 1. See the updated question.

Comment: The GROUP BY was there to ensure that only one image was selected. But if in the current scenario i use Group By, it returns one result still, but ignores the second ORDER BY property. It was working fine before this requirement turned up.

Comment: @salmanhijazi In that case, try something like this: --- SELECT * FROM models AS m INNER JOIN images AS im ON m.pk_model_id = im.fk_model_id WHERE im.sort =1 --- This gets all the records from the 'model' table as finds the corresponding image where 'sort' == 1. Is that what you need?

Comment: @w00 there's nothing wrong with the group by. It's acting like distinct in this context. It's not ideal, but not inherently wrong.

Comment: @kirbs Thats the problem with MySQL. People tend to use it in the wrong way because strict mode isn't on. Try to change that configuration and run a query like that. Do a query where you 'group by' one specific column and then try to display other column data aswell from the SELECT statement. Exactly like the Topic Starter is doing. It's not gonna work in STRICT mode, like it should.

Comment: Though I solved it on my own, I accepted because of all the help that w00 offered. Cheers